# Change dynamic json structure to key,value and children structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a dynamic JSON structure ex:

```
{
  "video": {
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "video_codec": "H264",
    "CBR": "4337025",
    "frame_rate": {
      "numerator": 25,
      "denominator": 1
    },
    "specified": {
      "numerator": 1,
      "denominator": 1
    },
    "gop": {
      "length": 50,
      "reference_frames": 3,
      "sub_gop": "StaticType"
    },
    "codec_details": {
      "profile": "Main",
      "level": "Level4",
      "entropy_encoding": "CABAC",
      "video_output": "AVC1"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to transform it to tree node

```
export class TrackDetailsNode {
  key: string;
  value: string;
  children?: TrackDetailsNode[];
}
```

Output Example:

```
{
  "key": "video",
  "children": [
    {
      "key": "width",
      "value": "1920"
    },
    {
      "key": "frameRate",
      "children": [
        {
          "key": "numerator",
          "value": "60"
        },
        {
          "key": "denominator",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need it in a recursive way. I want to build a tree from the provided JSON.
Tried multiple solution but is taking a long time to parse.

Comment: what should be sample output here of input json you gave above?

Comment: @AakashGarg I have edited the post I added output sample.

Comment: what happened to "height": 1080,
    "video_codec": "H264",
    "CBR": "4337025", and why kits "key": "video" instead of "name":"video"?

Comment: I didn't provide the full node it will be so long.

Comment: can you also give code which you have written?

Comment: why its "key": "video" instead of "name":"video"?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = {
  "video": {
    "width": 1920,
    "height": 1080,
    "video_codec": "H264",
    "CBR": "4337025",
    "frame_rate": {
      "numerator": 25,
      "denominator": 1
    },
    "specified": {
      "numerator": 1,
      "denominator": 1
    },
    "gop": {
      "length": 50,
      "reference_frames": 3,
      "sub_gop": "StaticType"
    },
    "codec_details": {
      "profile": "Main",
      "level": "Level4",
      "entropy_encoding": "CABAC",
      "video_output": "AVC1"
    }
  }
};

function transform(data, output, children) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
     let value = data[key];
     if (children) {
       if (typeof value === 'object') {
          const child = [];
          children.push({
             'key': key,
             children: child
          });
          transform(value, undefined, child)
       } else {
          children.push({
             'key': key,
             value
          })
       }
     } else {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          output.key = key;
          output.children = [];
          transform(value, undefined, output.children);
       } else {
          output.key = key;
          output.value = value;
       }
     }
  });
  return output;
}

console.log(transform(obj, {}));
```

Comment: @rami-sf please mark it as answer if it worked. i believe you have marked other post as answer.

Comment: @rami-sf this will fail in case `value` is `null` as `typeof null` is `'object'`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const INPUT = {
    "video": {
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 1080,
        "video_codec": "H264",
        "CBR": "4337025",
        "frame_rate": {
            "numerator": 25,
            "denominator": 1
        },
        "specified": {
            "numerator": 1,
            "denominator": 1
        },
        "gop": {
            "length": 50,
            "reference_frames": 3,
            "sub_gop": "StaticType"
        },
        "codec_details": {
            "profile": "Main",
            "level": "Level4",
            "entropy_encoding": "CABAC",
            "video_output": "AVC1"
        }
    }
};

const isObject = (obj) => obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';

const Transform = (input, isChildren) => {
    const output = isChildren ? [] : {};

    if (input && isObject(input)) {
        Object.keys(input).forEach(key => {
            const value = input[key];
            const val = isObject(value) ? Transform(value, true) : value;
            const valueKey = isObject(value) ? "children" : "value";

            if (isChildren) {
                output.push({
                    "key": key,
                    [valueKey]: val
                });
            } else {
                output.key = key;
                output[valueKey] = val;
            }
        })
    }

    return output;
}

const result = Transform(INPUT);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```